# How to render angular before print dialog?

Tags: angularjs

Problem is that print dialog is rendering before angular so when i click on print function i get `{{something}}` in print dialog and not real value...what can i do? I dont want to use $timeout because i think that solution is hackish :)

this is my print controller:

```
'use strict';
angular.module("printModule").controller('printController', ['$scope', '$window', function ($scope, $window) {

    $scope.ticketPin = localStorage.getItem("pin");
    $scope.payoutTime = localStorage.getItem("payoutTime");
    $scope.payoutAmount = localStorage.getItem("payoutAmount");

    if (typeof localStorage != 'undefined')
    {

        $window.print();
    }


}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put your logic in a directive's link function, you should be OK. Then just add the directive to your page or view you want to print.

Comment: can u help me with that?

Comment: Add a directive `angular.module("printModule").directive('print', function() {return {link: function() {$window.print()}});` then on the view for your controller just add <print></print> in the html. I suggest you put it as low as possible in your html so it executes as late as possible. The link function only executes after it loaded the DOM, so your {{}} expressions should have evaluated by then.

Comment: i get same result with directive :( i put <print></print> at the end but it call variables before print dialog again

Comment: Problem is that you need the print to wait for the digest cycle to complete. As far as I know there isn't an event for that :( Usually only a basic timeout with 0 or 1 millisecond will usually get you outside the digest. Understand you don't want timeouts, but might be the simplest solution in your case.  Sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: Your answer possibly lies in this post somewhere http://www.newyyz.com/blog/2014/12/15/understanding-priorities-in-angularjs-directive-definition-objects/